# How to Override Browser Remembering Position when loading a new Version of a Page?

Tags: asp.net, browser, bookmarks

I have a page called `results.aspx`. It shows a list of search results. I have a transport (for want of a better term) at the top and bottom of each page. One of these:

```
Previous   1   2   [3]   4   5   Next
```

Each of the text elements in the transport has a link in it, like this:

```
<a href="results.aspx?page=4" />
```

Page number varies, of course, based on the intended destination.

My problem is that because the root page name is the same, `results.aspx`, the browser always scrolls to the same position on the newly loaded page as it was on the page I just clicked away from. Or at least that's what I'm assuming is happening.

I've tried to create tags like

```
<a name="top">
<a id="top">
```

and change my link to either of

```
<a href="results.aspx?page=4#top" />
<a href="results.aspx#top?page=4" />
```

To no avail. I should point out that this is an inherited code base, so there could be nasties in the javascript that are overriding default behaviors.

Is there an obvious way to fix this? If it should be working by default, is there something in the code that I should be looking for that I should change or remove?

**-- EDIT --**

Here is a sample of the generated code taken from a browser:

```
<!-- Page Transport --> 
<ul> 
<li class="gray">first</li> 
<li class="gray">previous</li> 
<li class="current">1</li> 
<li><a href="lodging/results.aspx?page=2">2</a></li> 
<li><a href="lodging/results.aspx?page=3">3</a></li> 
<li><a href="lodging/results.aspx?page=4">4</a></li> 
<li><a href="lodging/results.aspx?page=2">next</a></li> 
<li><a href="lodging/results.aspx?page=20">last</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Yes, they're *just* hrefs and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why a browser would remember its position on the page!

**-- SOLUTION --**

Turns out the original developer included a javascript file, scrollsaver.min.js, which deliberately implemented this behavior. Removing this reference eliminated the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that those links are `<a>` tags and not buttons or `<a>` tags with onclick. If they are plain `<a>` tags what you describe should not happen. If those are postback buttons, somewhere in the code the scroll position is maintained by using [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx). Search for it. Once you can confirm that it is used, you can use [Resetting Scroll Position](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121505/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111407-1.aspx) to overcome this.

Comment: The links are definitely href's. I just doublechecked. Setting MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback predictably didn't work, but that's good to know.

Comment: Is this something that we can see?

Comment: This is strange. Those links can't maintain the scroll position. Since the server side logic is ruled out, may be something on the client side? There is no way you can show us this as working? Even a trimmed down version, if possible, would help a lot. From what is posted in the question, it should not and cannot happen. There must be something more.

Comment: @amit_g - hence my problem. I'm guessing it's something in the javascript, but there's so *much* of it being dragged into this page, I wouldn't know where to start. If I knew what to look for, I'd be able to fix it! Otherwise, I'd be posting an enormous amount of javascript.

Comment: @amit_g - holy crap! I found it. The original programmer included a file called scrollsaver.min.js. Commenting it out solved the problem!

Comment: @Bob Kaufman I am glad the mystery is solved :) Thanks for letting us know.